# Kubernetes pods cannot communicate outbound

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed Kubernetes v1.13.10 on a group of VMs running CentOS 7.  When I deploy pods, they can connect to one another but cannot connect to anything outside of the cluster.  The CoreDNS pods have these errors in the log:

```
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 app.harness.io.xentaurs.com. A: unreachable backend: read udp 172.21.0.33:48105->10.20.10.52:53: i/o timeout
 [ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 app.harness.io.xentaurs.com. AAAA: unreachable backend: read udp 172.21.0.33:49098->10.20.10.51:53: i/o timeout
 [ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 app.harness.io.xentaurs.com. AAAA: unreachable backend: read udp 172.21.0.33:53113->10.20.10.51:53: i/o timeout
 [ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 app.harness.io.xentaurs.com. A: unreachable backend: read udp 172.21.0.33:39648->10.20.10.51:53: i/o timeout
```

The IPs 10.20.10.51 and 10.20.10.52 are the internal DNS servers and are reachable from the nodes.  I did a Wireshark capture from the DNS servers,  and I see the traffic is coming in from the CoreDNS pod IP address 172.21.0.33.  There would be no route for the DNS servers to get back to that IP as it isn't routable outside of the Kubernetes cluster.

My understanding is that an iptables rule should be implemented to nat the pod IPs to the address of the node when a pod is trying to communicate outbound (correct?).  Below is the POSTROUTING chain in iptables:

```
[root@kube-aci-1 ~]# iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING -v --line-number
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 23 packets, 2324 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     1990  166K KUBE-POSTROUTING  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes postrouting rules */
2        0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    ens192.152  172.21.0.0/16        anywhere
```

Line 1 was added by kube-proxy and line 2 was a line I manually added to try to nat anything coming from the pod subnet 172.21.0.0/16 to the node interface ens192.152,  but that didn't work.

Here's the kube-proxy logs:

```
[root@kube-aci-1 ~]# kubectl logs kube-proxy-llq22 -n kube-system
W1117 16:31:59.225870       1 proxier.go:498] Failed to load kernel module ip_vs with modprobe. You can ignore this message when kube-proxy is running inside container without mounting /lib/modules
W1117 16:31:59.232006       1 proxier.go:498] Failed to load kernel module ip_vs_rr with modprobe. You can ignore this message when kube-proxy is running inside container without mounting /lib/modules
W1117 16:31:59.233727       1 proxier.go:498] Failed to load kernel module ip_vs_wrr with modprobe. You can ignore this message when kube-proxy is running inside container without mounting /lib/modules
W1117 16:31:59.235700       1 proxier.go:498] Failed to load kernel module ip_vs_sh with modprobe. You can ignore this message when kube-proxy is running inside container without mounting /lib/modules
W1117 16:31:59.255278       1 server_others.go:296] Flag proxy-mode="" unknown, assuming iptables proxy
I1117 16:31:59.289360       1 server_others.go:148] Using iptables Proxier.
I1117 16:31:59.296021       1 server_others.go:178] Tearing down inactive rules.
I1117 16:31:59.324352       1 server.go:484] Version: v1.13.10
I1117 16:31:59.335846       1 conntrack.go:52] Setting nf_conntrack_max to 131072
I1117 16:31:59.336443       1 config.go:102] Starting endpoints config controller
I1117 16:31:59.336466       1 controller_utils.go:1027] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoints config controller
I1117 16:31:59.336493       1 config.go:202] Starting service config controller
I1117 16:31:59.336499       1 controller_utils.go:1027] Waiting for caches to sync for service config controller
I1117 16:31:59.436617       1 controller_utils.go:1034] Caches are synced for service config controller
I1117 16:31:59.436739       1 controller_utils.go:1034] Caches are synced for endpoints config controller
```

I have tried flushing the iptables nat table as well as restarted kube-proxy on all nodes,  but the problem still persisted.  Any clues in the output above, or thoughts on further troubleshooting?

Output of kubectl get nodes:

```
[root@kube-aci-1 ~]# kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION    INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION          CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kube-aci-1   Ready    master   85d   v1.13.10   10.10.52.217   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64   docker://1.13.1
kube-aci-2   Ready    <none>   85d   v1.13.10   10.10.52.218   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64   docker://1.13.1
```

Comment: Can you share the response from `kubectl get no -o wide`?

Comment: How did you install Kube? This is up to your CNI plugin so my guess is whichever you picked isn’t set up correctly.

Comment: @bimal, I updated the post with the requested output.

Comment: @coderanger,   cluster was installed with kubeadm.  The CNI plug-in is the Cisco ACI CNI and it is set up per the documentation,  and appears to be correctly working for inbound access to the cluster.  Service IPs are reachable ingress to the cluster,  it's just outbound from the pods to the external network that is broken.

Comment: Can you reach those addresses from the node itself?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is necessary to use a subnet that is routable on the network with the CNI in use if outbound communication from pods is necessary.  I made the subnet routable on the external network and the pods can now communicate outbound.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use such a routable subnet?